# Cannot read property 'email' of null reactive form

Tags: angular

I have set the validator if the email is not valid and `registerForm.controls.email.errors.email` is giving me some problem. Its not working as expected and when I enter an email in that email field and then view the console then i see the error cannot read property email of null.

```
   <div *ngIf="loading" id="overlay"><div class="loader"></div></div>
          <form method="post" [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div id="tab-2" class="log-tab-content">


                <div class="login-left">

                  <div class="clearfix"></div>

                  <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.email.errors.email" data-tip="Email must be a valid email address"></div>
                  <input type="text"  formControlName="email" name="email" placeholder="Email *" tabindex="3"/>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>

                  <br>

                  </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <button type="submit" class="log-button log-button1">Register now</button>
              </div>

          </form>
```

ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../app.component.css', './register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {


  registerForm: FormGroup;


  constructor(private reg: AuthService, private data: DataService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
   }


  ngOnInit() {


    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({

      email: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.email]],

    })

  }


  onSubmit() {


}

}
```

Comment: Wow, is this _really_ a **minimal** example which demonstrates your issue? That template code is huge and cluttered. What should we be looking at? Please narrow it down to your actual issue.

Comment: Just the email field - https://i.imgur.com/SO7N1w7.png

Comment: "giving me some problem" What problem? Is there an error in the console? We are not magicians. We need information from you in order to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1.

Use `hasError` method to check form control errors

```
<div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.email.hasError('email')" 
          data-tip="Email must be a valid email address"></div>
```

Method 2.

Use `safe navigation (?.)`

```
<div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.email.errors?.email" 
          data-tip="Email must be a valid email address"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked with .hasError dont know why, coz in the tutorials it was .controls.email.errors.email

Comment: That should work aswell with safe navigation (?.) as I already mentioned. Both methods should work.